# Docker permission error after using --user option

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu-16.04

Python environmental error after after starting docker container with --user 1000:1000.

I am running a docker container which produces files in the mounted folder. To change the permission of created files I tried to run the container with --user. It allows container to run but when later I execute command in container it throws error.

What option should I use that it does not disturb the environmental variable and produce file with non-root permission.

***This is a downloaded container***

```
docker run --rm -v /xy:/gatk/xy --name cnv_gatk -u 1000:1000 -t -d broadinstitute/gatk:4.1.1.0

docker exec -t cnv_gatk gatk
```

```
ValueError: Unable to create the compiledir directory '/root/.theano/compiledir_Linux-4.15--generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid-x86_64-3.6.2-64'. Check the permissions.
08:54:05.201 DEBUG ScriptExecutor - Result: 1
08:54:05.201 INFO  DetermineGermlineContigPloidy - Shutting down engine
[September 19, 2019 8:54:05 AM UTC] org.broadinstitute.hellbender.tools.copynumber.DetermineGermlineContigPloidy done. Elapsed time: 0.04 minutes.
Runtime.totalMemory()=2142765056
java.lang.RuntimeException: A required Python package ("gcnvkernel") could not be imported into the Python environment. This tool requires that the GATK Python environment is properly established and activated. Please refer to GATK README.md file for instructions on setting up the GATK Python environment.
```